# save the image taken from camera to SQLite database and display them on computer?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

my application have a requirement to save the image taken from camera to sqlite database locally on mobile, then transfer the data from database from mobile memory to computer. The problem is i am not able to display the real image back onto computer though it shows in DB that the file is saved in PNG format? ANy help would be great. :)

Comment: my opinion is convert ur image to base64 string......... then if you want to display then fetch base64 string ,convert it into image and display .... i hope this will help

Comment: how u r sending your image to your computer? via webservice or other way?